# javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.createMessage call takes too long for large content

Tags: soap, javax.xml

The http response content is a soap message with a 100mb content.

**messageFactory.createMessage(null, responseinputstream)**
is taking 3 to 4 minutes, and the 
**responseSoapMessage.getSOAPBody()** 
takes another 4 minutes or more.
After this, since I am in WildFly application server, the transaction times out.

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
...
HttpEntity responseHttpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
...
InputStream responseContentStream = responseHttpEntity.getContent();
SOAPMessage responseSoapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(null, responseContentStream);
SOAPBody responseSoapBody = responseSoapMessage.getSOAPBody();
```

On creating a SOAPMessage from the InputStream through MessageFactory, I wonder why it takes that long.

Could it be due to some JAR issue?
I have two JARS in play: axis-1.4.jar, and saaj-impl-1.3.jar

However, while debugging, i found that the class used is SOAPMessageFactory1_2Impl from saaj-impl-1.3.jar.

Still, i could not reason out why it is taking more than 5 minutes to cross that two lines of code.

This is the SOAP XML in the response InputStream.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ReceiveDocumentResponse xmlns="https://NAMESPACEURL">
         <ReceiveDocumentResult>
            <base64Binary>HERE IS THE JPG IMAGE CONTENT OF SIZE 100 MB OR MORE</base64Binary>
         </ReceiveDocumentResult>
      </ReceiveDocumentResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please **note** that this method calls work reasonably good (quick) for contents less than 30 MBs.

**Any tips to go about troubleshooting, Or any tips to go for an alternative approach to parse out the content, are really appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the above logic with what is below. It does take a minute or so for 100 MB content, but it works consistently.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder domParser = null;
                    
domParser = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
domDocument =  domParser.parse(responseContentStream);
NodeList elementList = domDocument.getElementsByTagName("base64Binary");
Node element = elementList.item(0);
String base64String = element.getTextContent();
byte[]  rawData= Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);
document.setBData(rawData);
```

Whatever it is...